# Black boxes, missing or scaled images

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

In my iOS 8 app (Swift) I have setup a storyboard like so:

[image]

However, when I run the app I get something like the following result:

[image]

Notice how the images in top top-left and -right corners are not showing as expected. Also, sometimes the image in the top-right is not correctly scaled and has a greater height than expected. Notice how there's also a black box on the first result of the table view (this does not happen for any other results).

Both images are actually UIButtons with the image set, and have a size of 30x30 with 'view mode' set to "scale to fit".

EDIT:

Here is what it looks like with no results and the incorrectly scaled top-right image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting the "image" and "background" of each button to the same value (I did this in the storyboard editor, not through code). I feel like this is pretty hacky and doesn't answer cause of the issue. However, the images are displaying correctly and that was the aim of the game.